# Getting Data From Online (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to make an photo gallery app, so I want something like I upload pics to a webpage and it automatically gets displayed in that app.
I don't want to edit the coding for every single image and yess I don't want "WebView" all I want is a pure native android app, that gets data (images/audios/videos) from a webpage and display it in my native android app activity.

Comment: What have to tried so far?

Comment: Nothing... I Can't Figure Out From Where I Should Start It Up... 

Comment: I'm New In Android Development....

Comment: Do you have your own server supporting the webpage that you uses to upload the images? Do you have access to the directory on a server where you store those uploaded images?

Comment: No... Can't we use blog or google drive?

Comment: Or if it is difficult... so can we save the loaded webview page? I mean if i open app with any internet connection the page gets reloaded and load new contents. But if there is no netqork so display the last view it showed... is it possible?

Comment: You will need a have a url pattern for the image urls so you can use this pattern to find all the available image urls and then display them in your app.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is a grid view, you pass an array with the links to download the image and place them in each row.

Here is an [example] (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm) of how to use it.

Hope it helps